# Why is this svg not working in safari?

Tags: html, svg

The following svg is working in chrome and firefox, but is not working in Safari. And I haven't been able to test it in ie.

Safari does show the image, but does not apply the mask.

```html
<div class="widget-image-l">
    <svg width="645px" height="470px" viewBox="0 0 645 470" version="1.1">
        <g stroke="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <mask id="mask" fill="white">
                <path d="M38.5969948,-2.22080132e-11 C16.8456745,30.2125678 3.07305242,70.3781435 0.923015792,123.840504 C-7.15396842,324.681101 174,465.890038 341,469.890015 C508,473.889991 658.942386,367.295224 643.971193,180.147362 C637.875363,103.946248 607.401187,44.0482171 563.7625,-2.35331754e-11 L38.5969948,-1.42108547e-14 Z" id="path"></path>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#mask)">
                <image x="-1020" y="0" width="1867.94872" height="470" xlink:href="http://www.castleknockhotel.com/cmsGallery/imagerow/5904/resized/1600x400/cycling_passion_of_life_high_resolution_wallpaper_for_desktop_background_download_cycling_images_free.jpg" transform="scale(-1 1)">
                </image>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of safari you are using?

Comment: Just as a wild guess without having Safari at hand, does it work if you "de-exponentiate" the three exponented values? Ie. `d="M38.5969948,0 C16.8456745,30.2125678 3.07305242,70.3781435 0.923015792,123.840504 C-7.15396842,324.681101 174,465.890038 341,469.890015 C508,473.889991 658.942386,367.295224 643.971193,180.147362 C637.875363,103.946248 607.401187,44.0482171 563.7625,0 L38.5969948,0 Z"`

Comment: The mask works on Safari for me.

Comment: Whoops... It works for me too.

Comment: It didn't work in my full html and I found out what the problem was. There was also a <base href="/xxx"> specified in the html. Because of that the url(#mask) did not work. After removing the base tag it works!